# Completley stuck with add to cart solution with html and javascript. Also i'm a rookie at coding

Tags: javascript, function, responsive-design

```js
const ITEMS = [
    {
        id: 1,
        name: 'Armour S (black)',
        price: 69,
        image: './Vaporesso/Armour_s/black--vaporesso-armour-s-vape-kit_1.webp',
        qty: 1,
    },
]
const openBtn = document.getElementById('open_cart_btn')
const cart = document.getElementById('sidecart')
const closeBtn = document.getElementById('close_btn')
const backdrop = document.querySelector('.backdrop')
const itemsEl = document.querySelector('.items')
const cartItems = document.querySelector('.cart_items')
const itemsNum = document.getElementById('items_num')
const subtotalPrice = document.getElementById('subtotal_price')
let cart_data = []
openBtn.addEventListener('click', openCart)
closeBtn.addEventListener('click', closeCart)
backdrop.addEventListener('click', closeCart)
renderItems()
renderCartItems()
// Open cart
function openCart() {
    cart.classList.add('open')
    backdrop.style.display = 'block'
    setTimeout(() => {
        backdrop.classList.add('show')
    }, 0)
}
// Close cart
function closeCart() {
    cart.classList.remove('open')
    backdrop.classList.remove('show')
    setTimeout(() => {
        backdrop.style.display = 'none'
    }, 500)
}
// Add items to cart
function addItem(idx, itemId) {
    //find same item
    const foundedItem = cart_data.find((item) => item.id.toString() === itemId.toString())
    if (foundedItem) {
        increaseQty(itemId)
    } else {
        cart_data.push(ITEMS[idx])
    }
    updateCart()
    openCart()
}
// Remove cart items
function removeCartItem(itemId) {
    cart_data = cart_data.filter((item) => item.id != itemId)
    updateCart()
}
// Increase qty
function increaseQty(itemId) {
    cart_data = cart_data.map(item => item.id.toString() === itemId.toString() ? { ...item, qty: item.qty + 1 } : item)
    updateCart()
}
// Decrease qty
function decreaseQty(itemId) {
    cart_data = cart_data.map(item => item.id.toString() === itemId.toString() ? { ...item, qty: item.qty > 1 ? item.qty - 1 : item.qty } : item)
    updateCart()
}
// Calculate items number
function calcItemsNum() {
    let itemsCount = 0
    cart_data.forEach((item) => (itemsCount += item.qty))
    itemsNum.innerText = itemsCount
}
// Calculate subtotal price
function calcSubtotalPrice() {
    let subtotal = 0
    cart_data.forEach((item) => (subtotal += item.price * item.qty))
    subtotalPrice.innerText = subtotal
}
// Render items
function renderItems() {
    ITEMS.forEach((item, idx) => {
        const itemEl = document.createElement('div')
        itemEl.classList.add('item')
        itemEl.onclick = () => addItem(idx, item.id)
        itemEl.innerHTML = `
            <img src="${item.image}" alt="" />
            <button class="default-btn">Add to Cart</button>
            `
    })
}
// Display / Render cart items
function renderCartItems() {
    // remove everything from cart
    cartItems.innerHTML = ''
    // add new data
    cart_data.forEach(item => {
        const cartItem = document.createElement('div')
        cartItem.classList.add('cart_item')
        cartItem.innerHTML=`
                <div class="remove_item" onclick="removeCartItem(${item.id})">
                <span>&times;</span>
            </div>
            <div class="item_img">
                <img src="${item.image}"/>
            </div>
            <div class="item_details">
                <p>${item.name}</p>
                <strong>£${item.price}</strong>
                <div class="qty">
                    <span onclick="decreaseQty(${item.id})">-</span>
                    <strong>${item.qty}</strong>
                    <span onclick="increaseQty(${item.id})">+</span>
                </div>
            </div>
            `
        cartItems.appendChild(cartItem)
    })
}
function updateCart() {
    //rerender cart items with updated data
    renderCartItems()
    // Update items number in cart
    calcItemsNum()
    // Update subtotal price
    calcSubtotalPrice()
}
```

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Raleway:300,400,700');
@import url("https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Metal+Mania");
@font-face {
    font-family: "Booter - Zero Zero";
    src: url("Fonts/Booter - Zero Zero.woff") format("woff"),
         url("Fonts/Booter - Zero Zero.woff2") format("woff2");
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
}
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Spartan:wght@100;200;300;400;500;600;700;800;900&display=swap');
*{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    font-family: 'Spartan', sans-serif;
}
h1{
    font-size: 50px;
    line-height: 64px;
    color: #222;
}
h2{
    font-size: 46px;
    line-height: 54px;
    color: #222;
}
h4{
    font-size: 20px;
    color: #222;
}
h6{
    font-weight: 700;
    font-size: 12px;
}
p{
    font-size: 16px;
    color: #465b52;
    margin: 15px 0 20px 0;
}
.second-p1{
    padding: 40px 80px;
}
.second-m1{
    margin: 40px 0;
}
button.normal{
    font-size: 14px;
    font-weight: 600;
    padding: 15px 30px;
    color: #000;
    background-color: #fff;
    border-radius: 4px;
    cursor: pointer;
    border: none;
    outline: none;
    transition: 0.2s;
}
button:hover{
    opacity: 0.8;
}
body{
    width: 100%;
    min-height: 100vh;
    overflow-x: hidden;
}
/* cart */
.container {
    max-width: 900px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 0 1.5em;
}
.section-header {
    font-family: "Metal Mania";
    font-weight: normal;
    color: #333;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 2.5em;
}
.btn {
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: middle;
    padding: .67em .67em;
    cursor: pointer;
}
.btn-header {
    margin: .5em 15% 2em 15%;
    color: white;
    border: 2px solid #2D9CDB;
    background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, .1);
    border-radius: 0;
    font-size: 1.5em;
    font-weight: lighter;
    padding-left: 2em;
    padding-right: 2em;
}
.btn-header:hover {
    background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, .3);
}
.btn-play {
    display: block;
    margin: 0 auto;
    color: #2D9CDB;
    font-size: 4em;
    border-radius: 50%;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    padding: 0;
    text-align: center;
}
.btn-primary {
    color: white;
    background-color: #56CCF2;
    border: none;
    border-radius: .3em;
    font-weight: bold;
}
.btn-primary:hover {
    background-color: #2D9CDB;
}
.cart-header {
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 1.25em;
    color: #333;
}
.cart-column {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    border-bottom: 1px solid black;
    margin-right: 1.5em;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
    margin-top: 10px;
}
.cart-row {
    display: flex;
}
.cart-item {
    width: 45%;
}
.cart-price {
    width: 20%;
    font-size: 1.2em;
    color: #333;
}
.cart-quantity {
    width: 35%;
}
.cart-item-title {
    color: #333;
    margin-left: .5em;
    font-size: 1.2em;
}
.cart-item-image {
    width: 75px;
    height: auto;
    border-radius: 10px;
}
.btn-danger {
    color: white;
    background-color: #EB5757;
    border: none;
    border-radius: .3em;
    font-weight: bold;
}
.btn-danger:hover {
    background-color: #CC4C4C;
}
.cart-quantity-input {
    height: 34px;
    width: 50px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    border: 1px solid #56CCF2;
    background-color: #eee;
    color: #333;
    padding: 0;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 1.2em;
    margin-right: 25px;
}
.cart-row:last-child {
    border-bottom: 1px solid black;
}
.cart-row:last-child .cart-column {
    border: none;
}
.cart-total {
    text-align: end;
    margin-top: 10px;
    margin-right: 10px;
}
.cart-total-title {
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 1.5em;
    color: black;
    margin-right: 20px;
}
.cart-total-price {
    color: #333;
    font-size: 1.1em;
}
.btn-purchase {
    display: block;
    margin: 40px auto 80px auto;
    font-size: 1.75em;
}
/* Header start */
#header{
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: space-between;
    padding: 20px 80px;
    background: #E3E6F3;
    box-shadow: 0 5px 15px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.06);
    z-index: 999;
    position: static;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
}
#navbar{
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
}
#navbar li{
    list-style: none;
    padding: 0 20px;
    position: relative;
}
#navbar li a {
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 16px;
    font-weight: 600;
    color: #1a1a1a;
    transition: 0.3s ease;
}
#navbar li a:hover,
#navbar li a.active{
    color: #088178;
}
#navbar li a.active::after,
#navbar li a:hover::after{
    content: "";
    width: 30%;
    height: 2px;
    background: #088178;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: -4px;
    left: 20px;
}
#mobile{
    display: none;
    align-items: center;
}
#close{
    display: none;
}            
#product1{
    text-align: center;
    margin: 40px;
}
#product1 .pro-container{
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    padding-top: 20px;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
}
#product1 .pro{
    width: 23%;
    min-width: 250px;
    padding: 10px 12px;
    border: #cce7d0;
    border-radius: 25px;
    cursor: pointer;
    box-shadow: 20px 20px 30px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.02);
    margin: 15px 0;
    transition: 0.2s ease;
    position: relative;
}
#product1 .pro:hover{
    box-shadow: 20px 20px 30px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.06);
}
#product1 .pro img{
    width: 100%;
    border-radius: 20px;
}
#product1 .pro .des{
    text-align: start;
    padding: 10px 0;
}
#product1 .pro .des span{
    color: #606063;
    font-size: 12px;
}
#product1 .pro .des h5{
    padding-top: 7px;
    color: #1a1a1a;
    font-size: 14px;
}
#product1 .pro .des i{
    font-size: 12px;
    color: rgba(243, 181, 25);
}
#product1 .pro .des h4{
    padding-top: 7px;
    font-size: 15px;
    font-weight: 700;
    color: #088178;
}
#product1 .pro .cart{
    width: 40px;
    height: 40px;
    line-height: 40px;
    border-radius: 50px;
    background-color: #e8f6ea;
    font-weight: 500;
    color: #088178;
    border: 1px solid #cce7d0;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 20px;
    right: 10px;
}
/* Single product */
#prodetails{
    display: flex;
    margin-top: 20px;
}
#prodetails .single-pro-image {
    width: 40%;
    margin-right: 50px;
}
.small-img-group {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
}
.small-img-col{
    flex-basis: 24%;
    cursor: pointer;
}
#prodetails .single-pro-details{
    width: 50%;
    padding-top: 30px;
}
#prodetails .single-pro-details h4{
    padding: 40px 0 20px 0;
}
#prodetails .single-pro-details h2{
    font-size: 26px;
}
#prodetails .single-pro-details select{
    display: block;
    padding: 5px 10px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}
#prodetails .single-pro-details input{
    width: 50px;
    height: 47px;
    padding-left: 10px;
    font-size: 16px;
    margin-right: 10px;
}
#prodetails .single-pro-details input:focus{
    outline: none;
}
#prodetails .single-pro-details button{
    background: #088178;
    color: #fff;
}
#prodetails .single-pro-details span{
    line-height: 25px;
}
#proInfo {
    background-size: cover;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    text-align: center;
    flex-direction: column;
    padding: 14px
}
#proInfo .product-info img{
    width: 90%;
}
/* Backdrop */
.backdrop{
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
    z-index: 1;
    display: none;
    opacity: 0;
    transition: opacity 0.5s ease;
}
.backdrop.show{
    display: block;
    opacity: 1;
}
/* Side cart */
.sidecart{
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    height: 100vh;
    width: 350px;
    background-color: #fff;
    box-shadow: -10px 0 15px #c9cbce;
    z-index: 2;
    transform: translateX(110%);
    transition: transform 0.5s ease-in-out;
}
.sidecart.open{
    transform: translateX(0);
}
.cart_content{
    height: 100%;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
}
/* Cart header */
.cart_header{
    padding: 1rem;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #c9cbce;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    align-items: center;
}
.header_title{
    position: relative;
}
.header_title span{
    position: absolute;
    top: -5px;
    right: -20px;
    width: 20px;
    height: 20px;
    background-color: #088178;
    border-radius: 50%;
    color: #fff;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
}
.cart_header .close_btn{
    font-size: 2rem;
    cursor: pointer;
    transition: transform 0.2s ease;
}
.cart_header .close_btn:hover{
    transform: scale(1.1);
}
/* Cart items */
.cart_items{
    flex: 1;
    overflow-x: hidden;
}
.cart_item{
    position: relative;
    padding: 1rem;
    width: 100%;
    min-height: 150px;
    display: flex;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #c9cbce;
}
.remove_item{
    position: absolute;
    top: 10px;
    right: 10px;
    width: 20px;
    height: 20px;
    background-color: #ccc;
    border-radius: 50%;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    cursor: pointer;
}
.remove_item span{
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 20px;
    user-select: none;
}
.item_img{
    flex: 1;
}
.item_img img{
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    object-fit: contain;
}
.item_details{
    flex: 2;
    padding-top: 1rem;
    padding-left: 1rem;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    gap: 1rem;
}
.item_details p{
    color: #666;
}
.item_details .qty{
    align-self: flex-start;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    gap: 1rem;
}
.item_details .qty span{
    width: 30px;
    height: 30px;
    background-color: #fff;
    border-radius: 50%;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    font-size: 1.5rem;
    line-height: 1;
    cursor: pointer;
    box-shadow: 3px 3px 5px #c9cbce, -1px -1px 2px #c9cbce;
    user-select: none;
    transition: scale 0.2s ease;
}
.item_details .qty span:hover{
    scale: 1.1;
}
.item_details .qty span:active{
    scale: 1;
}
.qty span:first-of-type{
    font-size: 2rem;
    padding-bottom: 5px;
}
/* Cart Actions */
.cart_actions{
    padding: 1rem 2rem;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    gap: 1rem;
    border-top: 1px solid #c9cbce;
    box-shadow: 0 -5px 10px #c9cbce;
}
.cart_actions .subtotal{
    margin-bottom: 1rem;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: space-between;
    font-size: 14px;
    font-weight: bold;
    letter-spacing: 2px;
}
.cart_actions button{
    border: none;
    background-color: #000;
    color: #fff;
    border-radius: 15px;
    padding: 10px;
    font-size: 14px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    letter-spacing: 2px;
    cursor: pointer;
}
.cart_actions button:nth-last-of-type(1){
    background-color: #088178;
}
/*Start media query */
@media (max-width:799px) {
    .second-p1{
        padding: 40px 40px;
    }
    #navbar{
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: column;
        align-items: flex-start;
        justify-content: flex-start;
        position: fixed;
        top: 0;
        right: -300px;
        height: 100vh;
        width: 300px;
        background-color: #E3E6F3;
        box-shadow: 0 40px 60px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
        padding: 80px 0 0 10px;
        transition: 0.3s;
    }
    #navbar.active{
        right: 0px;
    }
    #navbar li{
        margin-bottom: 25px;
    }
    #mobile{
        display: flex;
        align-items: center;
    }
    #mobile i{
        color: #1a1a1a;
        font-size: 24px;
        padding-right: 60px;
    }   
    #close{
        display: initial;
        position: absolute;
        top: 30px;  
        left: 30px;
        color: #222;
        font-size: 24px;
    }
    #product1 .pro-container{
        justify-content: center;
    }
    #product1 .pro{
        margin: 15px;
    }
    #banner{
        height: 20vh;
    }
    #proInfo .product-info img{
        width: 100%;
    }
}
@media (max-width: 477px) {
    .section-p1{
        padding: 20px;
    }
    #header{
        padding: 10px 30px;
    }
    h1{
        font-size: 38px;
    }
    h2{
        font-size: 32px;
    }
    #hero{
        padding: 0 20px;
        background-position: 55%;
    }
    #feature{
        justify-content: space-between;
    }
    #feature .fe-box{
        width: 110px;
        margin: 0 0 15px 0;
    }
    #product1 .pro{
        width: 100%;
    }
    footer .copyright{
        text-align: start;
    }
    /* Single product */
    #prodetails{
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: column;
    }
    #prodetails .single-pro-image{
        width: 100%;
        margin-right: 0px;
    }
    #prodetails .single-pro-details{
        width: 100%;
    }
    #proInfo img{
        width: 100%;
    }      
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>WWV</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://pro.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.10.0/css/all.css"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <script src="cart2.js" defer></script>
</head>
<body>
    <!-- Open btn -->
    <button id="open_cart_btn">
        <img src="./cart.svg" style="width: 30px;" />
    </button>
    <!-- Backdrop -->
    <div class="backdrop"></div>
    <!-- Side Cart-->
    <div id="sidecart" class="sidecart">
        <div class="cart_content">
            <!-- Cart Header-->
            <div class="cart_header">
                <img src="./cart.svg" style="width: 30px;" />
                <div class="header_title">
                    <h2>Your Cart</h2>
                    <span id="item_num">0</span>
                </div>
                <span id="close_btn" class="close_btn">&times;</span>
            </div>
            <!-- Cart items-->
            <div class="cart_items">   
            </div>
            <!-- Cart actions-->
            <div class="cart_actions">
                <div class="subtotal">
                    <p>SUBTOTAL:</p>
                    <p>£<span id="subtotal_price">0</span></p>
                </div>
                <button>View Cart</button>
                <button>Checkout</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <section id="header">
        <a href="index.html"><img src="./WWV2.webp" class="logo" width="30%"></a>
        <div>            
            <ul id="navbar">
                <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
                <li><a class="active" href="shop.html">Shop</a></li>
                <li><a href="blog.html">Blog</a></li>
                <li><a href="about.html">About</a></li>
                <li><a href="contact.html">Contact</a></li>
                <a href="#" id="close"><i class="far fa-times"></i></a>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <div id="mobile">       
             <!-- Open btn -->
    <button id="open_cart_btn">
        <img src="./cart.svg" style="width: 30px;" />
    </button>
    <!-- Backdrop -->
    <div class="backdrop"></div>
    <!-- Side Cart-->
    <div id="sidecart" class="sidecart">
        <div class="cart_content">
            <!-- Cart Header-->
            <div class="cart_header">
                <img src="./cart.svg" style="width: 30px;" />
                <div class="header_title">
                    <h2>Your Cart</h2>
                    <span id="item_num">0</span>
                </div>
                <span id="close_btn" class="close_btn">&times;</span>
            </div>
            <!-- Cart items-->
            <div class="cart_items">   
            </div>
            <!-- Cart actions-->
            <div class="cart_actions">
                <div class="subtotal">
                    <p>SUBTOTAL:</p>
                    <p>£<span id="subtotal_price">0</span></p>
                </div>
                <button>View Cart</button>
                <button>Checkout</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
            <i id="bar" class="fas fa-outdent"></i>            
        </div>
    </section>
    <section id="prodetails" class="items section-p1">
        <div class="item single-pro-image">
            <img class="shop-item-image" src="./Vaporesso/Armour_s/black--vaporesso-armour-s-vape-kit_1.webp" width="100%" id="MainImg">
            <div class="small-img-group">
                <div class="small-img-col">
                    <img src="./Vaporesso/Armour_s/black--vaporesso-armour-s-vape-kit_1.webp" width="100%" class="small-img" alt="Black">
                </div>                
                <div class="small-img-col">
                    <img src="./Vaporesso/Armour_s/green--vaporesso-armour-s-vape-kit_1.webp" width="100%" class="small-img" alt="Green">
                </div>                        
                <div class="small-img-col">
                    <img src="./Vaporesso/Armour_s/orange--vaporesso-armour-s-vape-kit_1.webp" width="100%" class="small-img" alt="Orange">
                </div>                       
                <div class="small-img-col">
                    <img src="./Vaporesso/Armour_s/silver--vaporesso-armour-s-vape-kit_1.webp" width="100%" class="small-img" alt="Silver">
                </div>
                <div class="small-img-col">
                    <img src="./Vaporesso/Armour_s/yellow--vaporesso-armour-s-vape-kit_1.webp" width="100%" class="small-img" alt="Yellow">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="item single-pro-details">
            <h6>Vaporesso</h6>
            <h4>Armour S</h4>
            <h2>£69</h2>
            <select>
                <option>Select color</option>
                <option>Black</option>
                <option>Green</option>
                <option>Orange</option>
                <option>Silver</option>
                <option>Yellow</option>  
            </select>
            <input type="number" value="1">
            <button class=" item normal" type="button">Add to Cart</button>
    <script>
        var MainImg = document.getElementById("MainImg");
        var smallimg = document.getElementsByClassName("small-img");

        smallimg[0].onclick = function() {
            MainImg.src = smallimg[0].src;
        }
        smallimg[1].onclick = function() {
            MainImg.src = smallimg[1].src;
        }
        smallimg[2].onclick = function() {
            MainImg.src = smallimg[2].src;
        }
        smallimg[3].onclick = function() {
            MainImg.src = smallimg[3].src;
        }
        smallimg[4].onclick = function() {
            MainImg.src = smallimg[4].src;
        }      
    </script>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

I have researced for a few days now and tried different methods to try to make it work with my design, but now i'm completely stuck, because i seem to not find the correct answers online. All this is made by watching tutorials. As i'm still learning, then i don't understand a lot about it. But if i overcome this step with your help, i might actually learn something. Also my cart seems not to be responsive on mobile screen. Works on tablet and windows mode, but not on mobile. I have no idea what i'm doing wrong. Probably a lot of things...

Comment: Please take a look at [*How do I format my posts using Markdown or HTML?*](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting)

Comment: Thanks, First time using this platform. Took a while to figure it out